# Leaflet contextmenu не закрывается

Tags: javascript, leafletjs

Никак не могу разобраться почему не пропадает меню при клике вне карты. 
Меню пропадает только при клике на кнопку меню.

```
var contextMenuItems = [];
e.marker_drivers.forEach(function(element) {
    contextMenuItems.push({
        text: element["#value"][1]["#value"] + ". " + element["#value"][0]["#value"],
        index: element["#value"][1]["#value"],
        callback: function () {map_callback1C('appointDriver', [e.marker_id, element["#value"][1]["#value"]])}
    })
});

var _marker = new L.marker(
    coords, {
        // icon: new map_markerIcon({iconUrl: e.marker_icon}),
        icon: new L.NumberedDivIcon({
            number: e.marker_number,
            label: e.marker_label,
            labelClass: e.marker_label_type,
            iconUrl: e.marker_icon,
            marker_type: e.marker_type,
        }),
        marker_id: e.marker_id,
        marker_layer: e.marker_layer,
        marker_type: e.marker_type,
        nowDate: new Date(),
        move: [moveData],
        isSelected: false,
        contextmenu: true,
        contextmenuItems: contextMenuItems
    })
```

Помогите, пожалуйста :)

[Видео проблемы](https://youtu.be/hRQhVZelVyc)

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось, что обязательно нужна инициализация на уровне карты. Не достаточно только на маркер добавить меню.
**contextmenu: true**

```
map = new L.Map('map', {
        center: new L.LatLng(51.505, -0.04),
        zoom: 13,
        contextmenu: true,
    })
```